# Understanding site to site VPNs with overlapping IP addresses

Tags: vpn

I am a beginner in networking. What I do not quite understand about establishing site to site VPN connections is - what happens when you connect 2 networks and 2 servers have identical private IP addresses?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You end up having to do something called double NAT.  You NAT each side to a different network, tricking the two endpoints to pass traffic.

It's a bit complicated and not very elegant, but the only way to make it work.